# Can EVE-NG start on AMD Ryzen 7 1700x?

Tags: virtualization, amd-ryzen

I have chosen a processor for my new PC.  I would like to buy a Ryzen 7 1700x, but I need to run the *CCNP* and *CCIE* virtual labs on EVE-NG. Is there any problem with running EVE-NG on AMD hardware?

The EVE-NG website says that the EVE-NG team does not support AMD processors. I wanted to clarify, are there any known issues with AMD processors when running EVE-NG?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The site EVE-NG says that the EVE-NG team does not support AMD processors. I wanted to clarify are there any known issues with AMD processors when running EVE-NG?

Comment: Please provide all clarification as an edit to your question instead of submitting comments.

Comment: Do they say they don't support AMD simply because they haven't tried it or because they know of actual problems? If they simply haven't tried it then it may well work but it is just unsupported.

Comment: @Mokubai - The documentation (after 20 minutes of searching I found it) specifically indicates AMD-V is not supported.  So I doubt it's a case of it not being tested, but there is a specific reason, it's not supported. I have an answer ready to be submitted, which answers the question, but does not speculate what that reason might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a problem with running EVE-NG on AMD?

`EVE-NG` itself is a hypervisor.  This would be the reason `EVE-NG` supports VT-x but indicates it does not support AMD-V.  However, `EVE-NG` can still work without VT-x, it will have the following certain restrictions.

> - 64 bits (x86_64) appliances won’t work.
> - Poor performances should be expected with 32 bits (i386) appliances.

[EVE-NG System Requirements](http://www.eve-ng.net/documentation/installation/system-requirement)

> I wanted to clarify, are there any known issues with AMD processors when running EVE-NG?

There would indeed be issues with running EVE-NG in an AMD system.  You wouldn't be able to run 64-bit virtual appliances and 32-bit appliances would have a poor performance.  So if the CCNP and CCIE virtual labs require 64-bit hardware, you would be unable to run them, on your new AMD system.

It does mean that `EVE-NG` only supports being installed to physical Intel hardware since it appears to only support, Intel's hardware virtualization VT-x x86 extension.  However, that means you could, in theory, run a 32-bit virtual machine within a supported operating system, within a supported hypervisor (VMWare).

> Are AMD-V/RVI and Intel CPU VT-x/EPT interchangeable?

AMD-V and Intel VT-x are both x86 extensions that allow for hardware virtualization but they are NOT interchangeable since they are not identical.